# Why is my bottom div rendering outside of the window when using 50% height for the top and bottom?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a split screen layout with an upper half and lower half div. I have the parent container height set at 100%, and each inner div with a height set at 50%. However my lower div is rendering outside of the window and I can't see the bottom padding. If I lower the percentage slightly it looks okay, but when resizing the window the padding size doesn't stay consistent. I'd like to have an even 50% split of the top and bottom divs, with even padding all the way around.

https://jsfiddle.net/sherberthead/m96dh81q/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 50%;
}

#lower {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="top">
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
  </div>
  <div id="lower">
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
    <br> More inside content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because those % don't include the margin and padding, for the paddings try using the CSS `box-sizing: border-box;`. For the margins you have to find another solution (sorry, end of day for me, good luck). You can take a look at CSS `calc`, you can subtract % with px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `height` of each child `div` to `50%` and also add `padding` and `margin`, the actual space taken by each `div` becomes more than `50%` of the parent's `height`. This is because `padding` and `margin` are added to the `height`, resulting in the content overflowing.

To fix this, you can use the CSS `box-sizing` property. By setting it to `border-box`, the `padding` and `border` of the element will be included within its specified `width` and `height`.

This will not take into account the `margin` though, because margins take place outside the div. To account for the `margin` you need to remove the `margin` from the size of the `div`.

Below is an example.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Add this line */
}

#main {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: calc(50% - 40px); /* Adjust height to account for margin */
}

#lower {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: calc(50% - 40px); /* Adjust height to account for margin */
}
```